# Координаты точек самопересечения

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Дан файл координат вершин ломаной линии на плоскости. Определить, имеет ли ломаная линия самопересечения, если да, то записать в файл G координаты точек самопересечения. Реализовать на двоичных файлах с помощью структур данных (struct).

Comment: @morf, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Забыл добавить, работать необходимо с бинарным файлом:
1)записать бинарный файл с координатами(с этим проблем нету)
2)считать эти координаты из файла(возникли проблемы небольшие)
3)обработка данных и подсчёт точек пересечения(когда считаю точки пересечения, то у меня выдает ошибку мол "деление на 0" либо считает, но не выполняет условие)
4)запись в бинарном виде в файл G(с этим проблем нету)

Так вот, мне бы если точный код программы по которой считается правильно точка пересечения и было бы всё хорошо, с остальным я справлюсь...

А за ваш ответ спасибо, много мне объяснил он

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Заводите массив для сохранения туда точек пересечения
2. создаете какой-нибудь тип данных для для отрезков, составляющих ломаную. что-то вроде

   struct Line
   {
      Point start;
      Point end;
   }
3. Создаете и заполняете массив отрезков, составляющих ломаную.
4. создаете цикл, в котором бегаете по этому массиву
5. создаете еще один, вложенный цикл, в котором пробегаете по тому же массиву, но не с начала, а с текущего элемента из предыдущего цикла
6. в этом вложенном цикле определяете, пересекается ли текущий отрезок внешнего цикла с текущим отрезком внутреннего. Для этого решаете что-то вроде такого уравнения: (могу ошибаться, но детали можно поправить)  k1*x + b1 = k2*x + b2
   здесь k1 и b1  - коэффициенты из уравнения прямой первого отрезка
   а k2 и b2  - коэффициенты из уравнения прямой второго отрезка
   коэффициенты легко узнать, имея начальную и конечнуюточку отрезка.
7. Если х принадлежит отрезкам (может и не принадлежать, ведь у нас только отрезки, а не бесконечные прямые), то добавляете точку пересечения в массив
8. По выходу из обоих циклов пишете полученный массив в файл

Алгоритм явно не идеален, его можно (и, наверное ,нужно) оптимизировать, но это уже другая история